# How to restrict user registration based on user group

Tags: plugin, fix-my-code

I am wondering if someone can help me. I have developed a plugin that allows me to restrict the number of users registering on the site, but I would like to develop this further by restricting it to a particular user group, would anyone have any idea how i achieve this?

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plguserlimit extends JPlugin {

function __construct(&$subject, $config = array()) {
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);
}

public function onUserBeforeSave($user, $isnew, $new) {
    if ($isnew) {
        $limit   = $this->params->get('limit-text');
        $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = "select id from #__users";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->query();
        $num_rows = $db->getNumRows();
        if ($limit > $num_rows) {
            echo $erMsg = "Sorry but you have exceeded your allocated number of licenses.<BR><BR>Please press the back button on your browser to go back to the previous page.<BR><BR> If you wish to purchase more licences please contact customer support team ";
            die;
            JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(JURI::base(), $erMsg, 'error');
        }
    }
}
}


<extension type="plugin" version="3.0" group="user" method="upgrade">
<name>plg_user_register_limit</name> 
<creationDate>June 2014</creationDate> 
<license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license> 
<version>1.0.0</version> 
<description>
    <![CDATA[ 
        this plugin is used for limiting user registering
    ]]> 
    </description>
<files>
    <filename plugin="registerlimit">registerlimit.php</filename> 
    <filename>index.html</filename> 
    </files>
    <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_user_regitesrlimit.ini</language> 
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_user_regitesrlimit.sys.ini</language> 
        </languages>
        <config>
            <fields name="params">
                <fieldset name="basic">
                    <field name="limit-text" type="text" default="" label="Enter user Limit" description="Set limit" /> 
</fieldset>
</fields>
</config>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 3):

For restricting registration as per user-group you need to use #_user_usergroup_map table for checking number of users in a particular group.

SELECT *
FROM `#_user_usergroup_map`
WHERE `group_id` = 'GROUP_ID';

Here replace your specific group_id value.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, very helpful, i am not really fluent with XML in regards to calling from SQL, i would like to add a drop down menu in the plugin to be able to select the user group to restrict, how would i go about this please?

Comment: Use below code to display usergroups with xml

<field name="usergroups" type="usergroup" description="UserGroup"  label="Select Usergroup"    
     size="10"
    />